# SRC reference inside lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, font

Here is the css reference, I have uploaded the font to the static resource, the source org showing up the correct font face but once I package the app (yes I included the static resource) to the package and installed in a new org the font-family is not showing correctly.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Neutraface;
    src: url(/resource/fontNeutraface);  
}
```

Any help?

error I see in the console log:

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Neutraface"
> style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0): status=2147746065
> source:
> https://xxxxx-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/fontNeutraface

Comment: It could be namespace thing as well! Try using namespace__resource/fontNeutraface

Comment: yep it was `namespace`

Answer (score 3):

As Mohith Shrivastava pointed out it was namespace that was causing the issue:

Here is how I was able to fixed:

```
src: url(/resource/namespace__fontNeutraface);
```